# AS3 seeing every score

Tags: actionscript-3

I have recently taken up programming and encountered a problem when it comes to score display.  The score has not problem incrementing and displaying it is just that as the score updates it does not remove the last score.  After a dozen frames I have a jumble of scores displayed.  I have spent a few days google searching to see if I could find any type of answer but not seen a problem similar to this.

My Code:

```
public function  balldistance(event:Event){ // function called on ENTER_FRAME in order     to update the distance of the ball object

var txt:TextField = new TextField(); 
txt.text = "Distance:  " + String(balldist);
txt.x = 25;
txt.y = 25;
addChild(txt);

trace(balldist);  // I added this line in my code for troubleshooting purposes just so    I could see the balldist augment.
balldist += Ball5.dx;  // I am having the score(balldist) augment based on the distance the ball has traveled from its starting point.
}
```

A friend of mine suggested a removeChild(txt) but when i tried this it did not show the score updating.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are creating a new `txt:TextField` EVERY time ENTER_FRAME is triggered.

Try declaring/initializing it once, outside of that listener function:

```
var txt:TextField = new TextField(); 
txt.x = 25;
txt.y = 25;
addChild(txt);
```

Then on enter frame reference the SAME `txt` TextFeild instance, instead of making a new one over and over again:

```
public function  balldistance(event:Event){
  txt.text = "Distance:  " + String(balldist);
  balldist += Ball5.dx;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  After adding that change I no longer have that issue.